# RegEx to validate card holder name in ASP C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

Trying to validate card holder name in my website.
I tried the following regex

```
^([a-z]+[,.]?[ ]?|[a-z]+['-]?)+$
```

But it dosent validate against names like

```
JOHN DOE
LOREM IPSUM
ETC NAMES
```

I just want it to accept alphabets in 1, 2 or 3 words with singe space in between them. Example:

```
FIRST MIDDLE LAST
FIRST LAST
FIRST
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I just want it to accept alphabets in 1, 2 or 3 words with singe space in between them.

Try with following regex.

**Regex:** `^((?:[A-Za-z]+ ?){1,3})$`

**Explanation:** Atleast one character from character class `[A-Za-z]` followed by optional space. `{1,3}` ensures it's repeated atleast 1 and atmost 3 times.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fu9sMi/1/)**

**[C# demo on Ideone](http://ideone.com/gYHn2q)**

Comment: @kblok: And what are the shortcomings ?

Comment: C# won't understand the dollar at the end, removing that it will work

Comment: @kblok: I think you are mistaken. Check [C# demo](http://ideone.com/gYHn2q) and try your inputs in `line: 9`.

Comment: @Rahul awesome sir, up voting